# Polymorphic function call without duplicate code

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Suppose that all classes of a hierarchy implement a template member function `g`. All classes share the same implementation of two other functions `f1` and `f2` that call this template:

```
struct A {
    virtual void f1() {
        g(5);
    }
    virtual void f2() {
        g(5.5);
    }
private:
    template <typename T> void g(T) {std::cout << "In A" << std::endl;}
};

struct B: A {
    // Can I get rid of this duplicate code?
    virtual void f1() {
        g(5);
    }
    virtual void f2() {
        g(5.5);
    }
private:
    template <typename T> void g(T) {std::cout << "In B" << std::endl;}
};

struct C: A {
    // Can I get rid of this duplicate code?
    virtual void f1() {
        g(5);
    }
    virtual void f2() {
        g(5.5);
    }
private:
    template <typename T> void g(T) {std::cout << "In C" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A &a = b;
    a.f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Since the implementations of `f1` and `f2` are identical in all the classes, how can I get rid of the duplicate code and still have the polymorphic call in `main` work as expected (i.e produce the output "In B")?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the implementations of `f1` and `f2` in `A`, `B`, and `C` are *not* identical. Let's restrict it to `f1`s. One calls a function named `::A::g<int>`, another one calls a function named `::B::g<int>`, and the third one calls a function named `::C::g<int>`. They are *very far* from identical.

The best you could do is have a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)-style base:

```
template <class Derived>
struct DelegateToG : public A
{
  void f1() override
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->g(5);
  }

  void f2() override
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->g(5.5);
  }
};

class B : public DelegateToG<B>
{
  friend DelegateToG<B>;
private:
  template <class T> void g(T) { /*...*/ }
};

class C : public DelegateToG<C>
{
  friend DelegateToG<C>;
private:
  template <class T> void g(T) { /*...*/ }
};
```

Comment: I look at it another way: all of them call `this->g<int>`, where `*this` is the dynamic type of `a`. Why is this the wrong way to look?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Because `g` is not (and cannot be) virtual, which means normal compile-time rules apply to it. Note that compile-time rules are the default in C++. There are only a select few explicit exceptions to this (`virtual`, `dynamic_cast`, `typeid`).

Comment: Right. But `f1` is virtual. Within `f1` the type of `this` is the dynamic type of `a`. All I want is to have the same identical implementation of `f1` in the derived class without needing to repeat the implementation...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No, that's not true at all. Within `A::f1`, the type of `this` is `A*`. Within `B::f1`, the type of `this` is `B*`. The dynamic type comes into play when choosing *which* function to call: `::A::f1` or `::B::f1`? But inside those functions, everything is pure compile-time.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `g` are three completely unrelated function templates in three different scopes that happen to have the same unqualified name. `virtual` doesn't mean "repeat the definition in all derived classes and rebind all identifiers according to their meaning in each individual scope".

Answer (score 1):

You can just factor out the class-specific things that the template function uses, such as (in your example) the class name:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    virtual auto classname() const -> char const* { return "A"; }

protected:
    template <typename T> void g(T) {cout << "In " << classname() << endl;}

public:
    virtual void f1() { g(5); }
    virtual void f2() { g(5.5); }
};

class B
    : public A
{
private:
    auto classname() const -> char const* override { return "B"; }
};

class C
    : public A
{
private:
    auto classname() const -> char const* override { return "C"; }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{ static_cast<A&&>( B() ).f1(); }
```

Comment: This was just an example. In fact, the implementations of `g` vary a lot .

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I can't answer a question that you haven't posed. Sorry. Not telepathic.

Comment: `auto main() -> int` always makes me smile.